# Dynamic authorization delegation from a third party service to a client application on a given information system

Tags: authorization, oauth-2.0, permissions

As a company that wants to offer access to its services to a third-party known clients, I designed an authentication/permission system.

Here are our needs:

- As a service provider (A), I want to provide another company/customer (B) access to my services
- As A, I want to be able to identify B on my platform and give it access to a pool of resources only accessible by B (tenant)
- As B, I want to authenticate on A and give my users (C) temporary access to A with a dynamically created set of permissions
- As C, I want to access directly to A

Here is a flow I imagine that could answer those needs

[image: Permission Flow]

As you can see, it looks like an OAuth2 flow. But the client application never talks to the Authorization Server, because I want the third party service to dynamically choose which roles and which data the client application will be able to access.

- Could you please give me your opinion on this design?
- Do you consider it relevant?
- Do you see some other way to answer this kind of need?
- And do you know some already existing solutions to implement this?
  (Is OAuth2 adapted to that? Is Auth0 could, for instance, answer our
  needs in term of Authorization server?)

Comment: The way you've described it, the C is not your client. B is your client. If B is providing authorisation AND authentication, I think you are using the wrong design pattern. Let everything flow through B.

Comment: What does "As C, I want to access directly to A" even mean? Why is this a requirement? I suspect that you have an XY Problem centered around this one requirement and you are trying to build up a framework around this.

Comment: I agree with you. From A's point of view, B is the client
I think that A does not want to know all the diversity of roles that can exist through the different third party services. As a consequence, I consider B as my client.

We would like to offer some kind of library/SDK that will allow a customer owning B to easily develop, for instance, a mobile application C that will interact with A. And it seems that allowing a direct contact between A and C simplify the issue.
Your right,  "As C, I want to access directly to A" is not a real usecase, but is only deduced from technical constraints

Comment: I think, then, that this is not (yet) a security concern. You are still needing design help at the programming level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOUR REQUIREMENTS**

It seems these are the important requirements:

- Users from a third party need to be able to use your organisation's app (C in your picture)
- Your app (C) gets data from your organisation's services (A)
- Your services (A) also need to call the third party's API (B) on behalf of the user

**SOLUTION CHARACTERISTICS**

Solutions most commonly come down to plain old API / data design, rather than OAuth providing a quick solution.

**YOUR ORGANISATION'S DATA**

Give third party users logins to your app so that they can use your data. Aim to support [Federated Logins](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) so that end users use familiar passwords, and to enable single sign on across your app and those of third parties.

When the app gets data from A it will do so via an OAuth token that specifies the user id for your organisation. That is, your organisation's user id is not included in URLs or request bodies:

GET /your-api/resources/789

Your API will need to authorise access to resources based on who the user is, and also probably based on which third party they are from.

**THIRD PARTY DATA**

Your app's back end APIs (A) need to call (B) as a B2B API on behalf of the user. This link will use the third party's security solution. A common OAuth option is for Client Credentials flow to be used.

A B2B API call that deals with user specific resources will typically include a third party user id in the request URL or body:

- GET /partner-api/users/abc/resources/234

**YOUR USER DATA**

It feels like each user should be modelled in your system with certain properties:

- Your organisation's OAuth User Id (generated when created)
- Tenant id (which third party they are from)
- Third Party User Id
- Name + Email

Third party users would perhaps be onboarded by an administrator from that company, who supply the above details via a UI or API.

Comment: Seems that the best and more natural answer to my problem is clearly to avoid the link between A and C. Today, we also have a quite complex web application that allows reading and editing data stored in our domain. This app connects to A, and is deeply related to A business. So it seems that it should not connect to B. But we would like this app to be used by B users. That is one of the reason why a delegation of some permissions granted to B to a given B user, using the web app, seems to be a solution.
Could you see a way for third party user to access an app in my organization domain?

Comment: OK - interesting - I think this is more of an API design question than an OAuth one, so I've updated my answer and I hope some of this is useful in terms of designing your solution.

Comment: Interesting answer. A similar design has been thought, but a cons was a dependency from A toward B: In a perfect world, as A I want to minimize integration of B in my system, and I prefer B integrating A. Does it seems an unnecessary constraint to you? 
The more I read about authorization designs, the more I think that avoiding the dependency from A toward B is not a classic way of doing, and might be a bad idea, but it still seems logical to me.

Comment: A golden rule is that UIs and APIs from each organisation use that organisation's tokens. A B2B API is the common solution to bridge the two domains - this could work in either direction, as you say. I would prefer the option to get B to call A if that makes sense in terms of data. That way round you will be able to dictate the solution design.